# Sending NSArray parameter to a RESTful webservice using OAuthConsumer

Tags: iphone, arrays, rest, post, request

I'm using OAuthConsumer framework/helper classes to comunicate to RESTful webservices. I have the OAuth dance solved :-) but I have some functions that requires array parameters.

I'm setting parameters so

```
OARequestParameter *p0 = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"key"
                                                                value:@"value"];
NSArray *params = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:p0, nil];

OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                                               consumer:    [MyOAUthAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].consumer
                                                                  token:[MyOAUthAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].accessToken   // we don't have a Token yet
                                                                  realm:nil   // our service provider doesn't specify a realm
                                                      signatureProvider:[[OAHMAC_SHA1SignatureProvider alloc] init]]; // use the default method, HMAC-SHA1

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init]; //

[fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                     delegate:self
            didFinishSelector:@selector(requestTokenTicket:didFinishRESTWithData:)
              didFailSelector:@selector(requestTokenTicket:didFailTESTWithError:)];
```

But the WS is returning "Only arrays accepted".

My specifications says something like:

```
REST (POST parameters)

params[xxx]= int
params[yyy]= int
```

I think that this would be quite easy in PHP or Javascript, but I don't know how to send an Array parameter from an iPhone request, specifically using OAuthConsumer objects :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it adding parameters like these:

```
OARequestParameter *p0 = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"function"
                                                                value:functionName];

OARequestParameter *p1 = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"params[c_id]" 
                                                                value:@"2"]; 
OARequestParameter *p2 = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"params[a_id]" 
                                                                value:@"1"]; 
NSArray *params = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:p0, p1, p2, nil];
[request setParameters:params];
```